# DB2 into T-SQL. Alternative of NULLS LAST in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

```
FIRST_VALUE(B.LOC_X) OVER (PARTITION BY A.ACTIONBLOCKID ORDER BY CASE WHEN B.EVENT_TIMESTAMP <= A.ACTIONBLOCKENDTSTAMP THEN B.EVENT_TIMESTAMP END DESC NULLS LAST) AS DROPOFF_SCANLOC_X
```

I have this particular statement written in DB2 and since, `NULLS LAST` does not work in T-SQL. I am looking for a way to do the same thing in T-SQL.

Comment: The alternative would be to use `ISNULL` to provide an arbitrary value that you *know* is larger than any of the other values in that column.

Comment: Let's say the value is '1000' but how can that be incorporated in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative, as I mention, would be to use `ISNULL` to provide an arbitrarily high value so that `NULL` values are last. As, however, you are using a `CASE` expression here, then the arbitrarily high value would be in the `ELSE` clause:

```sql
FIRST_VALUE(B.LOC_X) OVER (PARTITION BY A.ACTIONBLOCKID
                           ORDER BY CASE WHEN B.EVENT_TIMESTAMP <= A.ACTIONBLOCKENDTSTAMP THEN B.EVENT_TIMESTAMP
                                         ELSE 1000
                                    END DESC) AS DROPOFF_SCANLOC_X
```

I use [your suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73581448/db2-into-t-sql-alternate-of-nulls-last-in-t-sql#comment129936962_73581448) of `1000` here, however, considering the column is called `EVENT_TIMESTAMP` I suspect that this is going to give you an error, or not the date you want (`1000` as a `datetime` is `1902-09-28 00:00:00.000`, which really isn't a "high value" date). More likely you want an arbitrarily date well into the future (like `'99991231'`).

Comment: Thank you for this. However, the resulting answer is different from what I was getting in DB2. The output that I get in DB2 is the second last value as per my output in T-SQL. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: To match the output, I had to use an impossible value in the past and now, it is working perfectly. Thank you @Larnu

Comment: If you want the `NULL` values to be the smallest, then you don't even need the `ISNULL`, @M_Arora . In SQL Server, `NULL`s are the *smallest* value.

Comment: I got confused because in DB2, NULLS are treated as largest value